# Spotfire intersect first 'n' periods

Tags: function, spotfire

Is there a way to use an Over and Intersect function to get the average sales for the first 3 periods (not always consecutive months, sometimes a month is skipped) for each Employee?

For example:

- EmpID 1 is 71.67 ((80 + 60 + 75)/3) despite skipping "3/1/2007"
- EmpID 3 is 250 ((350 + 250 + 150)/3).
- I'm not sure how EmpID 2 would work because there are just two data points.

I've used a work-around by calculated column using DenseRank over Date, "asc", EmpID and then used another Boolean calculated column where DenseRank column name is <= 3, then used Over functions over the Boolean=TRUE column but I want to figure the correct way to do this.

There are Last 'n' Period functions but I haven't seen anything resembling a First 'n' Period function.

```
EmpID    Date   Sales
1   1/1/2007    80
1   2/1/2007    60
1   4/1/2007    75
1   5/1/2007    30
1   9/1/2007    100
2   2/1/2007    200
2   3/1/2007    100
3   12/1/2006   350
3   1/1/2007    250
3   3/1/2007    150
3   4/1/2007    275
3   8/1/2007    375
3   9/1/2007    475
3   10/1/2007   300
3   12/1/2007   200
```

[image]

Comment: I wish they had a FirsPeriods function as well...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the solution depends on where you want this data represented, but here is one example

```
If((Rank([Date],"asc",[EmpID])<=3) and (Max(Rank([Date],"asc",[EmpID])) OVER ([EmpID])>=3),Avg([Sales]) over ([EmpID]))
```

You can insert this as a calculated column and it will give you what you want (assuming your data is sorted by date when imported).

You may want to see the row numbering, and in that case insert this as a calculated column as well and name it `RN`

`Rank([Date],"asc",[EmpID])`

**Explanation**

`Rank([Date],"asc",[EmpID])`

This part of the function is basically applying a row number (labeled as `RN` in the results below) to each `EmpID` grouping.

`Rank([Date],"asc",[EmpID])<=3`

This is how we are taking the top 3 rows regardless if Months are skipped. If your data isn't sorted, we'd have to create one additional calculated column but the same logic applies.

`(Max(Rank([Date],"asc",[EmpID])) OVER ([EmpID])>=3)`

This is where we are basically ignoring `EmpID = 2`, or any `EmpID` who doesn't have at least 3 rows. Removing this would give you the average (dynamically) for each `EmpID` based on their first 1, 2, or 3 months respectively.

`Avg([Sales]) over ([EmpID])`

Now that our data is limited to the rows we care about, just take the average for each `EmpID`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@Chris- Here is the solution I came up with

**Step 1:** Inserted a calculated column 'rank' with the expression below

```
DenseRank([Date],"asc",[EmpID])
```

**Step 2:** Created a cross table visualization from the data table and limited data with the expression below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Both @scsimon and ksp585 solutions get the desired end result. To fully understand though, is there not a way to "do something" OVER "FirstPeriods"n""?

Comment: Sadly no @Chris you can only go in reverse. You could use my method and replace 3 with a property control that you can set to what ever you want dynamically and accomplish the same thing as first n

Comment: @Chris - In my solution, you could do the same (dynamically control the number of months to be considered) in the 'Limit data using expression' and replace 3 with the document property